# How to make chat like UI with chat bubbles in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have some JSON data in `dummyData`. I am not sure how can I place the chat bubbles on left and right according to the `direction`. I am using Material UI and context API. Image for the reference. I don't want to use any library other than material UI.

[image]

Currently, every chat bubble is positioned to the left. How to position bubbles according to the `direction`. Code so far ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-feather-47rbt)):

```
    import React from 'react';
import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    container: {
        bottom: 0,
        position: 'fixed'
    },
    bubbleContainer: {
        width: '100%'
    },
    bubble: {
        border: '0.5px solid black',
        borderRadius: '10px',
        margin: '5px',
        padding: '10px',
        display: 'inline-block'
    }
}));

const ChatLayout = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dummyData = [
        {
            message: '1: This should be in left',
            direction: 'left'
        },
        {
            message: '2: This should be in right',
            direction: 'right'
        },
        {
            message: '3: This should be in left again',
            direction: 'left'
        }
    ];

    const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i = 0) => (
        <div className={classes.bubbleContainer}>
            <div key={i++} className={classes.bubble}>
                <div className={classes.button}>{obj.message}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
    return <div className={classes.container}>{chatBubbles}</div>;
};

export default ChatLayout;
```

Comment: I have made some css and logical  changes in your codesanbox .check updated one :  https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-faraday-zmkdm-updated-zmkdm , https://zmkdm.csb.app/

Comment: This is perfect! Please make it an answer. How do I align "bubbleContainer" to the bottom? I tried adding "justify-content: flex-end !important" to "bubbleContainer" but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you mean you want bubble start from bottom to top?

Comment: Yes. I had used "bottom: 0, position: 'fixed'" to make it happen.

Comment: check now, I have updated style.css

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate div of chat bubble and apply CSS. And where you are receiving messages append the bubble div to your user list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).